# Click on an image to reload current page with an other language (jquery, php and sessions)

Tags: php, jquery, session

I need to have a simple translate method for my pages.
For this, i have to click on a country flag to show the country language version.
I have lot of pages, so i want to reload the current page with the correct language when clicking and not reloading the index page.

I coded this, and it works, but only on Chrome (???) and it's not perfect because i need 2 clicks to show the translate page.

my script on index.php :

```
<script src="data/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>        

<script>
    function gotoLang(id){
         $.ajax({
                url: 'langage.php',
                type : 'GET',
                data: 'lang='+id
         });
        document.location.reload(false) // to reload page after edit session['langage']
        }
</script>
```

my html code :

```
<a href="#" onclick="gotoLang('fr')"><img src="flags/France.png"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="gotoLang('it')"><img src="flags/Italy.png"></a>
```

and the langage.php page which is called :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['langage'] = $lang;
//echo $_SESSION['langage'];
?>
```

So this way is working... But not with firefox ?! and i need to click 2 times to show the correct file.
Any idea to do better ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `$.ajax` time to complete since it is asynchronous.

Right now the `reload()` is happening before the ajax is done and will cause an abort of the ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'langage.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: 'lang=' + id
}).done(function (response) {
    /* should validate response here */
    document.location.reload(false);
}).fail(function(){
    alert('Ooops...server problem');
});
```